# If $|x|+|y|>|x+z|$, then is $y > z, y<z$, or $y=z$, or not determinable?

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

If $|x|+|y|>|x+z|$, then is $y > z, y<z$, or $y=z$, or not determinable?

I thought about cases, $x>0,x<0,y>0,y<0,z>0,z<0.$ Plugging numbers is unconvincing to me.

Comment: $$\begin{align*}
|x|+|y|&> |x+z|\\
|-1|+|1| &> |-1+0|\\
|-1|+|1| &> |-1+1|\\
|-1|+|-1| &> |-1+0|
\end{align*}$$

Comment: "Plugging numbers" is the perfect way to achieve some results. You should learn when it can be used, and get used to it.

Comment: "*Plugging numbers is unconvincing to me*".  What @DavidK commented.  That is, if you are trying to conclude that either $y > z$, or $y < z$, and you *plug numbers* that show counter-examples to each assertion, then you have completely resolved the question.

Comment: @peterwhy That could be an answer just like that. I'd vote for it.

Comment: @DavidK The current quality standard discourages answers to questions that may be considered low quality, so I would rather put short answers here without such risk.

Comment: @peterwhy +1 : You got that right.

Comment: @DavidK Hello. What is wrong with my answer? Do you see a mistake?If my answer is wrong, I will delete it

Comment: @user2661923 Do you see a mistake in my answer?

Comment: @user2661923 actually we can choose the easier way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a simpler mathematical way without using numbers, you can see that this result is indeterminable.

Note that $\forall a,b\in\mathbb R$, we have

$$|a|+|b|≥|a+b|$$

Hence putting $y=z\neq 0$ and $y=-z\neq 0$ with some $x$, such that the inequality $|x|+|z|>|x+z|$ is always correct. This implies that even at least one of the results $y>z$ or $y<z$ or $y=z$ cannot always be correct.

Comment: +1 : to your answer.  I totally overlooked that.  I have withdrawn my comments.  As a point of constructive criticism, I suggest mentioning that equality only occurs if [1]$a = 0$ or $b = 0$ or [2] $a,b$ have the same sign (both positive or both negative).  If you had mentioned this, then I would have **gotten it**.

Comment: @user2661923 Yes you're right, exactly. I wanted to do that, then I said I'll do it, I forgot because I was lazy..

Comment: @user2661923  I got your point. Also, Thank you for your credit.

Answer (score 0):

Here are simple approaches that don't use numbers:

- 1. Putting $x=-z$ , we get

$$|y|+|z|>0$$

Then, you can choose infinitely many pair $y,z\neq 0$, such that all possible cases: $y>z$ or $y<z$ or $y=z$ hold.

- 2. Fix $x=0$, you get $|y|>|z|$. This implies, you can also use the same argument. But, note that in this case $y=z$ doesn't hold.